# In C, what's the typical way to handle multiple arguments that are "list"-like?

Tags: c, unix, command-line-arguments, filenames

Suppose I have some program called "combine" that takes input of "red", "green" and "blue"-type files to produce an output file (let's say "color.jpg")... BUT the *number* of each type is arbitrary. Let's also suppose that there's no way to determine what type the file is except through how the user classifies them. What do people usually do in this case?

For instance, on the command line, some of the approaches might be:

```
command red1,red2,red3 green1,green2 blue1 color.jpg
```

This comma-approach breaks down if commas can appear in the filenames. It's the approach I like the most though. Another idea would be

```
command "red1 red2 red3" "green1 green2" "blue1" color.jpg
```

but this approach also has trouble with spaces in names.

I could also require ASCII files containing lists giving the files of each type:

```
command redlist greenlist bluelist color.jpg
```

but this requires lugging around extra files.

Further ideas? Is there a standard LINUX way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way would be this:

```
command --red red1.jpg --red red2.jpg --blue blue1.jpg
```

With short options:

```
command -r red1.jpg -r red2.jpg -b blue1.jpg
```

With bash shorthand:

```
command -r={red1,red2}.jpg -b blue1.jpg
```

(The above gets expanded by the shell so it looks like the previous invocation.)

Doing things this way avoids arbitrary limitations like "no commas in filenames" and also makes your program more interoperable with standard *nix utilities like `xargs` and so on.

Comment: Note that the last one requires the program to accept `-r=red1` as equivalent to `-r red1`.

Comment: True.  If not, just say `-r{red1,red2}.jpg` - omitting the equals sign is slightly uglier but might be more "portable" among different command line argument libraries.

Comment: And that requires the program to accept the single argument `-rred1` as a synonym for the two arguments `-r red1`. For short options, I don't think that's typical; `-abc` usually means `-a -b -c`. But long options often do accept arguments with `=`: `--red={red1,red2}.jpg`

Comment: I think most command line processors do support -rred sort of things, because they know that -r requires an argument.  In fact, it is practically canon to have no space after -I (eye) or -l (ell) when invoking a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is accepting:

```
command -r redfile1 redfile2 -b bluefile1 blue2 blue2 -g green1
```

so that:

```
command -r red* -b blue* -g green*
```

is possible.

Comment: You might be able to do this with ad-hoc command line processing, but if you use a standard library of a sufficiently high level, doing it this way may actually be more work, because it's not very typical (can you name a standard program that does it this way?).

Comment: I totally agree, but I have no idea why this is not standard or at least common :)

Comment: I really like this answer and wish I could make it too.